# Count selected checkboxes by category in form (PHP)

Tags: php, checkbox, count

I have a form in my website where you have to check some things using checkboxes. Checkbox names are different according to how many "points" the user gets for checking this checkbox. For clarity all the names of checkboxes are i.e `name="this_gives_1"` if checkbox gives you 1 point. `name="this_gives_5"`gives you obv. 5 points. Now at the end I sum up all the points using:

```
$points_in_total= 0;

$question_one_point = $_POST['this_gives_1'];
$question_one_point_count = count($question_one_point);

$points_in_total = $points_in_total + $question_one_point_count;

$question_two_point = $_POST['this_gives_2'];
$question_two_point_count = count($question_two_point)*2;

$points_in_total = $points_in_total + $question_two_point_count;

$question_three_point = $_POST['this_gives_3'];
$question_three_point_count = count($question_three_point)*3;

$points_in_total = $points_in_total + $question_three_point_count;

$question_five_point = $_POST['this_gives_5'];
$question_five_point_count = count($question_five_point)*5;

$points_in_total = $points_in_total + $question_five_point_count;

$question_eight_point = $_POST['this_gives_8'];
$question_eight_point_count = count($question_eight_point)*8;

$points_in_total = ceil(($points_in_total);
$email_message .= "You got ".$points_in_total";
```

Now what I want to do here is, that I want to add a system that checks some things and then using simple boolean tells, if this user is something or not.

For example if there is checkboxes that are "Porche", "Ferrari", "Fiat" and user checks even one of them, then the system will think: number of checked checkboxes in category "cars" > 0, so this user likes cars. And if the number is for example 0, then it says: "I think you dont like cars".

So can I use ID for all the anwsers related to cars by doing:

```
<input id="car" name="this_gives_5[]" type="checkbox" value="Ferrari">Ferrari
<input id="car" name="this_gives_1[]" type="checkbox" value="Fiat">Ferrari
<input id="fruit" name="this_gives_1[]" type="checkbox" value="Banana">Banana
<input id="fruit" name="this_gives_3[]" type="checkbox" value="Apple">Apple
<input id="fruit" name="this_gives_5[]" type="checkbox" value="Tomato">Tomato
```

and then using ID's to count, how many "cars" are checked (or fruits ect.)?

```
if ($points_in_total_of_ID_cars > 2) {
    $email_message .= "You really like cars!";
    } elseif ($lukumaara > 0) {
    $email_message .= "You like cars";
    } else {
    $email_message .= "You dont like cars, because you didn't check one";
    }
```

So once again, how do I

1) build this so, that I can count one spesific category of items;
2) create simple if-elseif to give the user feedback of something like in the example above?

Comment: Don't worry about the "ceil()". there is use for that, because the points total are divided by 2,82 for one personal reason.

Comment: change the name of your cars and fruits checkboxes to for example "cars[]" and "fruits[]" then in php you can do : `if(count($_POST['fruits']) > 0) { echo you like dem fruits }`

Comment: Yes, but how can i then know, how many points i will get from that spesific anwser? I now use name="" to get the right amount of points

Comment: Plenty of ways, you can incorporate it in the value, like instead of Banana you have Banana-3 , with the number being the points. then in your loop you split the value and get the number value for the points.

Comment: Oh you mean that the "point collector" only uses the last letter of the name, which is a nuber and the "will you like fruits" excludes last two letters "-1" or "-3" to see in what category it goes?